# GWT support for HTML5

Tags: java, gwt, html, websocket

Does GWT support HTML5? I mean especially Canvas and WebSockets?

Regards

Comment: i removed the app-enginge tag, as this question is not related to app-engine at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this video (from Google developers) can be of interest

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW--Wlf9EFs

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers still do not support these technologies without plugins, therefore direct support is not available.

WebSockets requires support from the server also, once again most servers do not support it yet.
for WebSockets in GWT You could download this and use it:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-websockets/

For the HTML5 Canvas look here:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/
or here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas

Comment: Most (now, all as of IE9) browsers do support Canvas now. Websockets are different. And I'd like to point out that HTML5 does *not* include WebSockets. (Same goes for Geolocation). They may be considered for addition to the spec, but they are separate standards right now.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a GWT library for handling Media elements (Video and Audio). It allows for full progammatic control and allows access to all the events that the elements are supposed to fire. All wrapped up in a nice GWT widget/element combo.

[GWT HTM5 Media (GitHub)](https://github.com/tweakt/gwt-html5-media)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they have nothing to do with GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [GWT explicitly supports some HTML5 features](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5.html).

Cavas is supported, Websockets are not supported by default, but there are projects around which address this task:

- [gwt-websockets](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-websockets/)
- [WebSockets for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ws/)
- more to be found by googling (I can't recommend a particular project from personal experience, I'm afraid)