# HTML5 website widgets on GWT?

Tags: gwt, html, widget

Can i develop widgets on gwt for html5 web site? And if yes, what do you think about such compilation of technologies?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502291 of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GWT still compiles down to Javascript you can make HTML5 widgets by either using JSNI or DOM Manipulation setting Attributes for HTML5 Properties.

If you wanted to do vector drawing (canvas) you can use: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas

Answer (score 0):

GWT 2.2 adds support for canvas.

[Release Notes](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/ReleaseNotes.html#HTML5)

[Demo](http://gwtcanvasdemo.appspot.com/)

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/gwtcanvasdemo/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgwt%2Fgwtcanvasdemo%2Fclient)